# Хочу перенести значение переменной из одной функции в другую

Tags: python

Моя программа:

```
def open_file():
    with open("Исходное однострочное сообщение.txt","r") as f:
        return(f.read())
def open_result_file(f):
    with open("Зашифрованное однострочное сообщение(шифр Цезаря).txt","r") as f:
        return(f.read())
def deshifr_file_cezar(file_message,key):
    result=[]
    alf = ['А','Б','В','Г','Д','Е','Ё','Ж','З','И','Й','К','Л','М','Н','О','П','Р','С','Т',
            'У','Ф','Х','Ц','Ч','Ш','Щ','Ъ','Ы','Ь','Э','Ю','Я']
    alf2 = ['а','б','в','г','д','е','ё','ж','з','и','й','к','л','м','н','о','п','р','с','т',
            'у','ф','х','ц','ч','ш','щ','ъ','ы','ь','э','ю','я']
    symbol=['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0','!','@','"','#','№','$',';','%','^',':',
            '&','?',',','*','(',')','-','_','=','+',' ','\n']
    for i,txt in enumerate(file_message):
        if txt.isupper():
            if txt not in symbol:
                mes=alf.index(txt)
                ky=alf2.index(key)
                y=(mes-ky)%33
                result.append(alf[y])
            else:
                for h in symbol:
                    if txt==h:
                        result.append(h)
        else:
            if txt not in symbol:
                mes=alf2.index(txt)
                ky=alf2.index(key)
                y=(mes-ky)%33
                result.append(alf2[y])
            else:
                for h in symbol:
                    if txt==h:
                        result.append(h)
    return "".join(result)

def shifr_file_cezar(file_message, key):
    result=[]
    alf = ['А','Б','В','Г','Д','Е','Ё','Ж','З','И','Й','К','Л','М','Н','О','П','Р','С','Т',
       'У','Ф','Х','Ц','Ч','Ш','Щ','Ъ','Ы','Ь','Э','Ю','Я']

    alf2 = ['а','б','в','г','д','е','ё','ж','з','и','й','к','л','м','н','о','п','р','с','т',
        'у','ф','х','ц','ч','ш','щ','ъ','ы','ь','э','ю','я']

    symbol=['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0','!','@','"','#','№','$',';','%','^',':',
        '&','?',',','*','(',')','-','_','=','+',' ','\n']

    for i,txt in enumerate(file_message):
        if txt.isupper():
            if txt not in symbol:
                mes=alf.index(txt)
                ky=alf2.index(key)
                y=(mes+ky)%33
                result.append(alf[y])
            else:
                for h in symbol:
                    if txt==h:
                        result.append(h)
        else:
            if txt not in symbol:
                mes=alf2.index(txt)
                ky=alf2.index(key)
                y=(mes+ky)%33
                result.append(alf2[y])
            else:
                for h in symbol:
                    if txt==h:
                        result.append(h)
    return "".join(result)

def result_file_cezar(root, file_message, key):
    lbl_out = Label(root,text="Файл зашифрован", font=50)
    k=shifr_file_cezar(t,key)
    f=open("Зашифрованное однострочное сообщение(шифр Цезаря).txt","w")
    f.write(str(k))
    f.close()
    lbl_out.place(x=460,y=345)

def result_deshifr_cezar(root,file_message,key):
    lbl_out = Label(root,text="Файл расшифрован", font=50)
    k=deshifr_file_cezar(c,key)
    with open("Расшифрованное однострочное сообщение(шифр Цезаря).txt","w") as f:
        f.write(str(k))
    lbl_out.place(x=460,y=845)
t=open_file()
f=open("Зашифрованное однострочное сообщение(шифр Цезаря).txt","w")
c=open_result_file(f)
f.close()
tp4=StringVar()
txt4 = Entry(root,textvariable=tp4,width=50)
btn_decezar_file = Button(root, text="Расшифровать однострочный файл методом Цезаря",command=lambda: result_deshifr_cezar(root,c,tp4.get()),
              font="Calibri 15",height=2,width=35,bg="green")
```

Я хочу перенести значение `k` из процедуры `result_file_cezar(root,file_message,key)` в функцию `open_result_file(f)`, то есть вместо `return(f.read())` надо вернуть значение `k`, но в новом файле ничего не выводится, когда я пытаюсь это сделать. Как это можно исправить?

Comment: Поправьте отступы в коде и приложите текст ошибки.

Comment: там не то что ошибка, там просто ничего не выводится( в новом файле, где я пытаюсь расшифровать содержимое файла некоторым способом)

Answer (score 0):

Можно создать отдельную функцию, которая возвращать значение `k`.

Можно сделать глобальную переменную `k` и открывать в каждой функции как `global k`

И можно в функцию `open_result_file(f)` передавать функцию `shifr_file_cezar(t,key)` как значение. Это, на мой взгляд, самый оптимальный вариант

**UPDATE**

в функцию, которую передаём как параметр, тоже нужно передать параметры, вот так:

```
def func_1(t):
    print(t)


def func_2(a, b):
    return a + b


func_1(func_2(1, 2))
```

Comment: а как передать функцию, как значение?

Comment: `open_result_file(shifr_file_cezar(t,key))`

Comment: выскакивает ошибка invalid syntax и выделяет скобку перед t

Comment: "Можно сделать глобальную переменную k и открывать в каждой функции как global k" - нельзя. Если у вас в коде есть глобальная переменная, у вас плохой код.

Comment: а обязательно надо конкретные параметры передавать?

Comment: Когда вы определяете функцию, задаёте ей параметры. В вашем случае `shifr_file_cezar(t,key)` должна принимать два **ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНЫХ** параметра `t` и `key`. Иначе вы должны определить функцию так: `shifr_file_cezar()`, в этом случае параметры не нужны

Comment: не получается((

Comment: как по-другому можно исправить?